# wordpress category name in shortcode php

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, shortcode

i want to display the current category name in code below in my sidebar but i cant. Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

```
<?php
    $weather_city = the_category_name();
    if ($weather_city)
    echo do_shortcode('[forecast location="' . $weather_city . ', Greece" caption="" measurement="C" todaylabel="Σήμερα" datelabel="%%weekday%%" highlow="%%high%%&deg; / %%low%%&deg;" numdays="4" iconset="Incredible" class="css_table_class"]'); ?>
```

Comment: it looks like you are missing some bracets for the `if`

Comment: Not needed if only one line of code is there... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_categories = get_the_category(); // array of objects
if (!empty($current_categories)) {
    $category = reset($current_categories); // take the first one
    $weather_city = $category->cat_name;

    echo do_shortcode('[forecast location="' . $weather_city . ', Greece" caption="" measurement="C" todaylabel="Σήμερα" datelabel="%%weekday%%" highlow="%%high%%&deg; / %%low%%&deg;" numdays="4" iconset="Incredible" class="css_table_class"]');
}
```

Comment: Are you trying this on a post page?

Comment: if i remove do_shortcode the category is provided right but the short code works not..

Comment: In that case there must be a problem with your forecast plugin.

Comment: Since this question was about getting a category name, I think it would be better if you post a new question about your plugin.